# AutoHotkey, don't get the solution

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, autohotkey

I really need your help. I trying to program an AutoHotkey script but I not quite getting a working solution.

My current AutoHotkey script is:

```
#IfWinActive Guild Wars 2
shift & 1::
Send, 1
sleep 500
Send, y
return
```

So when I’m in Guild Wars and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>1</kbd>, it will do my macro. So I can spam <kbd>1</kbd> (while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and it will do it again and again. The problem is, I always need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>. My desire is, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> ONE time, it will do the macro always when I spam <kbd>1</kbd>. But it should do the macro only till I play another key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>F1,</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>). So if I play another key, it should be doing the normally <kbd>1</kbd> (so no macro).

- With pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> one time and spamming <kbd>1</kbd> = my macro
- After pressing a key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>F1,</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> it should do the normal <kbd>1</kbd> (no macro).

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
#ifWinActive Guild Wars 2

shift::  ; Shift to toggle auto-spammer
    hotkey, ifWinActive, Guild Wars 2
    hotkey, $1, shift_1, on
    loop {
        input, keystroke, l1 v, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
        if keystroke not contains 1
            break
    }
    hotkey, $1, off
return

shift_1:
    send 1
    sleep 500
    send y
return
```

Alternatively, if you want the <kbd>Shift</kbd> toggle to modify `X` hotkeys from <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>:

```
#ifWinActive Guild Wars 2

X = 9  ; Set this to the number of keys you want to be auto-spammable

loop %X% {  ; Create hotkeys 0-X
    hotkey, ifWinActive, Guild Wars 2
    hotkey, $%a_index%, autoSpammer
}

shift::  ; Shift to toggle auto-spammer
    autoSpam = on
    loop {
        input, keystroke, l1 v, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
        if regExMatch(keystroke, "[^0-9]")
            break 
    }
    autoSpam = off
return

autoSpammer:
    thisHotkey := regExReplace(a_thisHotkey, "[^0-9]")
    if autoSpam = on
    {
        sendInput %thisHotkey%
        sleep 500
        sendInput y
    }
    else
        send %thisHotkey%
return
```